# How can I cluster a small area (say a circle of 20 meters diameter) in OSM to check the different node Ids in the area

Tags: openstreetmap, gps, osm2pgrouting

I have a node ID(Say Z) which will be in the road/way. How do I find the node IDs around this point Z in certain radius.

Comment: With an API or a local OSM file or a database?

Comment: I have a OSM file for a specific state as well. But how do I find the node IDs within certain radius using the information from OSM file?

Comment: By going through all nodes of the file and comparing their location. Alternatively better import the file into a spatial database.

Answer (score 1):

When using the famous overpass-api, you can have a look at the "around" parameter.

See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL for "around".

Comment: I tried to look at overpass API. It expects me to give me a tag so that I can look for specific information. (like bus_stop). I am looking for all the OSM ids in the road within a radius. I could not find a way to do it.